# Nested transactions in django?

Tags: django, transactions

Let's say I have model `app1.models.ModelOne` defined with save decorated with `@commit_on_success`. All the exceptions caught in `ModelOne.save()` are re-raised. Works fine on `model_one_instance.save()`.

However, in `app2` I need to make series of insertions to `ModelOne` and rollback all of them if any of them fails. How do I accomplish this?

Decorating `app2.jobs.do_the_inserts` with `@commit_on_success` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested transactions are database-specific, so you're going to lose portability. If you need that, I'd consider doing is changing the simple @commit_on_save for something more flexible:

```
def save(commit=True):
  if commit:
    db.start_transaction()
    try:
        self.real_save()
        db.commit_transaction()
    except backend.DatabaseError, e:
        db.rollback_transaction()
        raise e
  else:
    self.real_save()
```

Otherwise, you can run arbitrary SQL commands so you can call `db.connection.cursor().execute()` with whatever your backend database uses, probably with a check to not do anything for other backends so you can still use sqlite for local testing.

Depending on your app structure, it might also be possible to use [savepoints](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#savepoint-rollback). I've written a few utilities which do something like this:

- Start transaction
- Perform mandatory commands
- Start optional statements:

  - start savepoint
  - execute
  - savepoint commit or rollback
- More mandatory SQL
- commit

Comment: I think your solution is solving a different problem. Suppose you have two methods, say, foo() and bar() and both are decorated with @commit_on_success. If foo() calls bar(), when do you expect django to send a COMMIT to the database? 

I think the intuitive answer is that django issues a single COMMIT at the end of the foo() method. Django, however, sends two COMMITs, one at the end of bar() and then another one at the end of foo(). The consequence of this is that transaction decorators can never be nested or Very Bad Things will happen.

Comment: Not really "database-specific", nested transactions are available in all major databases via the `SAVEPOINT/ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT/RELEASE SAVEPOINT` commands -- which seem to work the same way in PostgreSQL, SQLite and MySQL.

Comment: Within Django, savepoints were not supported prior to 1.4 (note that the original post was in 2009). Even then, you still have the usual InnoDB / MyISAM debate - which isn't to say you shouldn't use the feature but more that developers should think about what they should do if support isn't enabled.

Comment: @LoganBowers having poked around this a little I think the outer commit_on_save should open a transaction and the inner should drop a save point. Exceptioning out of the inner one would then roll back to the save point. Exceptioning out of the outer one would roll back entirely. This scheme seems to best map to naive user expectations.

Comment: @LoganBowers implementation as a simple function decorator implies that once you exit the function the decorator runs, even if the function is nested in another transaction decorated func

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS server nested transactions may not be supported at all.  Properly implementing nested transactions in a DBMS is actually quite difficult because you end up having to share locks between transactions.

However, what you're describing doesn't sound like nested transactions.  I don't know whether django supports XA transactions but what you describe could be achieved with a TP monitor architecture and an XA aware DBMS (which is most of them these days).

If your platform doesn't have support for XA transactions you would have to structure the transactions so a record of how to roll them back is stored somewhere.  Something along the lines of the 'Unit of Work' pattern described in Fowler's *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture* might give a good start for the architecture of such a subsystem.

Comment: DBMS is pg 8.3; 
I am wondering if there is a way to do this via ORM layer.

Comment: PG 8.3 supports XA transactions but I don't know if Django supports them.  The article at this link goes into transaction management on django http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2008/09/01/transaction-management-in-django/